# Cached newssite packaged app: which local storage to use?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So I'm building a Chrome Packaged App that updates every x hours in the background, checks if the newssite has new articles & adds them to a "local storage"-solution.

That way the user would be able to view the articles when there is no internet connection available. (for instance when he's on the train or so)

Now, I need to actually store this data somewhere locally. I'd like to work with an MVC structure, so a somewhat structured solution would be great. I did some research, and found a number of ways I could do this:

IndexedDB - Key value storage, not so great for images, limited in space
Storage API - Only small amounts of string data, unstructured
FileSystem API - Unstructured

So, I've found 3 ways to store the data, non is really perfect. Am I missing out on a way to solve my problem? Would it be an idea to use IndexedDB for text and structure (it can save objects) and use the FileSystem API to store the images in a sandboxed area?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API. In an extension or app if you use this API you can store objects unlike the FileSystem api.

You could also consider using the [syncFileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem.html) API that gives you access to save and syncronise data to google drive so your saved data will be available across each device of the user.

Comment: what about images? I can't possibly put those in chrome.storage.
We're talking about a fairly big amount of data here.

I thought about using syncFileSystem, but at this point, I'd rather not.. since it complicates the background script..

Comment: You could use chrome.storage with the unlimitedStorage flag : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Comment: but the page states that the unlimitedStorage _permission applies only to Web SQL Database and application cache (see issue 58985)._

Comment: chrome.storage offers 5MB, but unlimitedStorage removes the limit, "This value will be ignored if the extension has the unlimitedStorage permission." - http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html#local-properties